# Requring TFS commit comments with VS2013 and VS2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, commit, visual-studio-2013

As I understand it, the TFS **Changeset Comments Policy** may be set by any permitted user to require all team members to add a comment when making a check-in. Clearly, this must be a setting on the TFS server, rather than a local setting on the machine of the developer who makes the change. Yet my reading on this indicated that a curious notion. Prior to VS2013, this policy was not bundled with Visual Studio; rather it was in the Productivity Power Tools (PPT). Various references all indicate that *each member of the team* had to have PPT installed in order for the policy to be effective. [One source](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jjameson/archive/2009/10/31/recommended-check-in-policies-for-team-foundation-server.aspx) wrote it as "if you don't have the Power Tools installed, you can still override the check-in policy". But if this is indeed a server setting, how would one be able to override it? That's part 1 of my question.

Part 2 of my question is now, with the advent of VS2013 that has the Changeset Comments Policy packaged in, I presume that the policy will just work. But what happens if there are some users running VS2013 and some running VS2012--does the same limitation still exist, i.e. that the VS2012 users with PPT can still override the check-in policy?

Answer (score 2):

In TFS the checkin policies requirement are server side, but the checkin policies them selves are client side. So for users that don't have the checkin policy installed this policy will always be not fulfilled. the Comments policy is no exception. When you don't have the policy available on your computer you will just get a more cryptic failed checkin policy.

This goes for both standard/bundled policies and custom made policies. Note that you can always override failed policies. There is no way to refuse the developers the option of overriding, even for missing policies.

As a side note I can say that tfs power tools has a feature that allows for automatic distribution of checkin policies. But then you of course will have to make sure that all developers have tfpt installed. for TFS/VS2012/13 this feature might be included, but I'm not sure. You can have a look at this blog post if this is relevant

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/youhana/archive/2011/03/27/distributing-custom-check-in-policies-amp-wit-controls-using-team-members.aspx